# pytorch multiprocessing - TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing, distributed-computing

I want to configure the Multiple gpu environment using ‘torch.multiprocessing’ and ‘torch.distributed’. However, I received the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_custom.py", line 398, in <module>
    mp.spawn(init_process, args=(world_size, backend), nprocs=world_size, join=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 230, in spawn
    return start_processes(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method='spawn')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 188, in start_processes
while not context.join():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 150, in join
raise ProcessRaisedException(msg, error_index, failed_process.pid)
torch.multiprocessing.spawn.ProcessRaisedException: 

-- Process 0 terminated with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 59, in _wrap
fn(i, *args)
  File "/root/USRGAN_step2/train_custom.py", line 390, in init_process
fn(rank, size2)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

My code is as follows.

```
def run(rank, size2):
...

def init_process(rank, size2, fn, backend='gloo'):
    """ Initialize the distributed environment. """
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '29500'
    dist.init_process_group(backend, rank=rank, world_size=torch.cuda.device_count())
    fn(rank, size2)


###################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    world_size = torch.cuda.device_count()
    backend = 'gloo'
    mp.spawn(init_process, args=(world_size, backend), nprocs=world_size, join=True)
    #mp.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)
    processes = []
    size2 = 4
    for rank in range(size2):
        p = Process(target=init_process, args=(rank, size2, run))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

I followed the tutorial(https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/dist_tuto.html) as it was, but this error occurred. And I don't find the cause of error.

Comment: Compare `args=(world_size, backend)` with `init_process(rank, size2, fn, backend='gloo')`. You're passing the backend string as `fn`.

Comment: Thank you. But i get this error message 'RuntimeError: Default process group has not been initialized, please make sure to call init_process_group.'

Comment: I would note that your code is not "as it was" in the tutorial. Instead of `mp.set_start_method` you have `mp.spawn`. Surely that's a non-trivial change.

Comment: When I use `mp.set_start_method`, I got error `RuntimeError: Default process group has not been initialized, please make sure to call init_process_group.` too. So I use `mp.spawn` instead of `mp.set_start_method`. But I got same error.

Comment: Your `mp.spawn` call is also different from the tutorial. I don't want to compare them line by line and anyway I don't know this library. But did you also try just copy-pasting the tutorial example as-is, to see if that works?

Comment: Yes I did, But same error occured. `RuntimeError: Default process group has not been initialized, please make sure to call init_process_group.` Thank you for your concern.

Comment: OK, then there's nothing else I can help with. Since this is an official tutorial that doesn't seem to work for you, you should ask the PyTorch community. See links at https://pytorch.org/#community-module. Either you are missing some configuration (that might or might not be obvious by reading earlier chapters of the tutorial), or the tutorial needs fixing.